# how to get value from solidity contract using java

Tags: java, ethereum, solidity

my solidity contract is following:

```
contract SimpleStorage {
uint storedData;

function set(uint x) {
    storedData = x;
}

function get() constant returns (uint retVal) {
    return storedData;
}}
```

and generate the abi is following:

```
[ { "constant": false, "inputs": [ { "name": "x", "type": "uint256" } ], "name": "set", "outputs": [], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "get", "outputs": [ { "name": "retVal", "type": "uint256", "value": "0" } ], "type": "function" } ]
```

and referenced by https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC,

How to invoke  **get** funtion and **get the value** by using java (not js)?

Answer (score 3):

[web3j](https://github.com/web3j/web3j) caters for this very use case. It generates Smart Contract wrappers in Java from a Solidity compiled binary and ABI file.

Once you've generated the wrapper code with web3j, you will be able to deploy, then call the methods on the above contract example as follows:

```
SimpleStorage simpleStorage = SimpleStorage.deploy(
    <web3j>, <credentials>, GAS_PRICE, GAS_LIMIT,
    BigInteger.ZERO);  // ether value of contract

TransactionReceipt transactionReceipt = simpleStorage.set(
        new Uint256(BigInteger.valueOf(1000))),
        .get();

Uint256 result = simpleStorage.get()
        .get();
```

Note: the additional `get()` is because web3j returns Java Futures when interacting with Ethereum clients.

See the [docs](http://docs.web3j.io/smart_contracts.html#solidity-smart-contract-wrappers) for further information.

Comment: #Conor i have following your answer and it is very nice to understand but i am facing some issue can you please look this and help me  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44719819/web3j-not-working-with-contract-function

Comment: #conor I want to call the smart contract methods from android app. so I deployed the smart contract using truffle framework and generate the wrapper class for the smart contract and it creates the.java file in android project so I call the set and get methods into android but it shows some error at by giving credentials details of waller path . That line is  org.web3j.crypto.Credentials credentials = WalletUtils.loadCredentials(" ","/usr/local/Cellar/test3/keystore/UTC--2018-03-13T09-19-38.721370320Z--191a1be7c53236f916af5512329a5092f70fab59 "); .i got error like wallet address is not correct

Comment: please look this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50654417/how-to-call-the-smart-contract-methods-from-android-app-using-web3j

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example in Java (under Spring Boot)
Good luck
http://blockchainers.org/index.php/2016/09/22/static-type-safety-for-dapps-without-javascript/